# Script that scans my network

Tags: linux, bash

I have a question I want to run a script that scans my network and that I can see with devices are up in my network. I want to paste some arguments also in the script

When I run the script:

```
 ./ping.sh --xx-YY 20 50
```

Output:

```
192.168.0.20 is down 

192.168.0.21 is up 
..................................

192.168.0.50 is up
the argument -t , counts 200 by the last digit for ex. ./ping.sh -t 20 output: 192.168.0.220 is up
```

But my problem is the argument --up en -mac I want when I run the script ./ping.sh --up , its only display the computers there are up And the argument - mac is also a problem when I run the script I want to display the ip addresses and de mac address after the computers are ping**

Can anybody help me with this 2 arguments ?

This is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[ -n "$@" ]]
do
    case "$1" in

    -h|--help)
    Extension=1
    shift
    ;;

    -XX-YY)
    Extension=2
    shift
    min=$1
    shift
    max=$1
    shift

    ;;

    --up)
    Extension=3
    shift
    end=$1
    shift
    ;;

    -t)
    Extension=4
    shift
    count=$(($1+200))
    shift
    ;;
    esac
done

if [ "$Extension" -eq 1 ] ; then

    echo "dit is de help"

fi


if [ "$Extension" -eq 2 ] ; then

for ((n=$min ; n<=$max ; n+=1))
do
ip=192.168.0.$n
if ping -c 1 -w 1 ${ip} > /dev/null 2> /dev/null >> logping.txt; then
echo "${ip} is up"
else
echo "${ip} is down"
fi
done


fi

if [ "$Extension" -eq 3 ] ; then


                ip=192.168.0.$end
                if ping -c 1 -w 1 ${ip} > /dev/null 2> /dev/null >> /logping.txt; then
                        echo "${ip} is up"

                fi

fi

if [ "$Extension" -eq 4 ] ; then

ip=192.168.0.$count
if ping -c 1 -t 1 ${ip} > /dev/null 2> /dev/null >> logping.txt; then
echo "${ip} is up"
else
echo "${ip} is down"
fi
fi
```

Comment: Don't crosspost to 4 sites (SE, Ask, SU and U&L). This is generally considered to be rude and inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Let's we do some order.

**Case #5: `-mac` or, better, `--ip`**
There are no problems in the "case statement" lines of your case #5.
Neverteless I strongly suggest you to change the name of the option from **`-mac`** to **`--ip`**. Mac Address and Ip Address are different concepts and in this case I think `ip` is the appropriate one.

Matter of style: even if it is not a strict rule it is common the use of a single `-` if the following option is composed by only one letter, and the use of a double  `--` if composed by more than one letter. E.g. in your same example you have `-h` and `--help`. (Correct even the `--xx-YY`). Scripts are inclined to last in time and it will be strange after to see it with only one `-`.

Back to the code of #5 you can use something similar to:

```
if [ "$Extension" -eq 5 ] ; then
  ip=192.168.1.$mac
   if nmap -sP -n -r $ip | grep "is up" >/dev/null ; then
      echo "${ip} is up"
   fi
fi
```

Errors in that attempt:
`ip=192.168.0.$mac` is defined on `192.168.`**`0`**`.xxx` and the following line it is not used the variable `$ip`, and instead is used the subnet `192.168.`**`1`**`.0/24`. The nested `if... then fi` block is not closed by a `fi`.

---

**Case #3: `--up` **
If I correct understand what you mean, you want to show somehow the list of all the *up* host in that subnet. So you do not need to specify the *end* variable for the *IP*, but you should scan all the subnet `192.168.1.xxx` .

You can use something like the following commands

```
if [ "$Extension" -eq 3 ] ; then
  sudo nmap -sP -n -r 192.168.1.0/24 | grep -E "Nmap scan|MAC Address:"
fi
```

**Update: References about MAC Address**

- [nmap.org](http://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html)
- [Resolving MAC Address from IP Address in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120153/66388)
- [Equivalent of iwlist to see who is around?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/96700/66388)
- [Can I use nmap to discover IPs and mac addresses?](https://serverfault.com/questions/148113)

Comment: Thank you very much it't works but there is one problem 
when i run the script ./ping -mac 185
the display is 192.168.0.185 but i want also print the mac address of this device

Comment: Now I understand why you called it `--mac`. BTW this is another question... :) Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212187/is-it-possible-to-get-the-mac-address-for-machine-using-nmap) or some help of `nmap`.

Comment: I don't understand what I can do for show also the mac addres of the computer

Comment: Updated answer. If you execute with `sudo` it will answer with Mac Address too. BTW: take the use to post questions that require a single answer and not multiple answers. If the answer you receive, moves your problem to another point, search for a solution of that point and after that if you are not able to find do another question. So it will be useful for other people too ;)